# ruby on rails app and google app scripts

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, google-apps-script

I have a app which runs on ruby on rails and mysql database. I need to generate couple of reports. Presently I am generating csv file but my Idea is to integrate with the google docs, as soon as a user opens a particular doc automatically it has to sync with the my rails app and fetch the data from the database and display in the google docs.

I need little heads up.I have gone through the docs, but couldn't figure out the way of doing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [to_google_spreadsheets](https://github.com/firmafon/to_google_spreadsheet) gem. It is well documented and seems to have all the functionality you are looking for.

Cheers,
Sean

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write an onOpen in your gdoc. From there call urlfetch to your app.